# RLC Circuit with Dependent Source

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks

I am trying to solve the attached practice problem from Hayt's 8e of *Engineering Circuit Analysis* but I am struggling to find a solvable differential equation for the circuit.

I am trying to use KVL to derive the DE, but I can't find an expression for the voltage across the dependent current source. Can anyone help me out?

I've also attached what I have so far.[image]

[image]

Comment: How about making it \$V_x\$ ? Then see what you can get out of it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for the hint - I tried that, but I can't seem to find an expression for Vx as a function of Vc which is ultimately the dependent variable I'm hoping to solve for in the DE.

Comment: If you want to derive DE, then start by writing down DEs for each individual component. Then show us what you've got and we might help you from there.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've edited my question with what I have so far, I just can't seem to figure out what to do with that Vx. Other than that, everything is in terms of Vc.

Comment: Either I am too rusty on this stuff or you can write down an equation for \$v_c\$ ignoring much of other stuff:  \$I_c = I_L = -3v_c = \frac{1}{C}\frac{dv_C}{dt}\$

Comment: Nope, you are spot on. I don't know why I didn't go directly to that, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: +1 for being very clear how you use KVL